# would anything happen if I pass a pointer function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers

I wonder that what would happen if I pass a **pointer function** as a parameter, is it valid and is the memory of that **pointer function** stuck somewhere in RAM?

This is the example:

```
char* Function1(char *array1, int N) {
    ...
    return newChar;
}
char* Function2(char *array2, int M) {
    ...
    return newChar;
}

char* newArray = Function2(Function1(oldArray, N), M);

delete[] oldArray;
delete[] newArray;
```

Whether `Function1(oldArray, N)` after having been called will have anything wrong with it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If your program shows some problem: Check that you have exactly as many `delete[]`s as you have `new[]`s.

Comment: This is perfectly legitimate, but you have to be careful that `newChar` survives the function return (and that `oldArray` is suitably initialised somewhere). We can't decide that for you, because you haven't shown us your code.

Comment: Maybe not directly relevant, but why are you using C-style strings, with all the accompanying `new` / `delete` baggage that goes along with them, instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Im sorry, so do I need to `delete[] newArray` after doing `char* newArray = Function2(Function1(oldArray, N), M);`? Because I used only one `new` for `oldArray`

Comment: @SnowyField You need exactly one `delete[]` for every `new[]` you've used. No more, no less. If you've used `new[]` to place a pointer in a smart pointer, the count could however be a bit different.

Comment: @SnowyField If you are unsure about if you have memory leaks in your program, you can use tools to analyze it for you. If you use `g++` or `clang++` to compile, add the options `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` when you compile. Then run the program and see if it reports anything odd.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you very much!!! it is really helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **valid** to write these kind of function calls but as you suspected, the memory you've allocated for the character array in subsequent function calls will be stuck in RAM, a **memory leak**. Let me explain with the following code.

```cpp
char* Function1(char *array1, int N) {
    char *newarray = new char [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
        newarray[i] = array1[i] + 1;
    return newarray;
}

char* Function2(char *array2, int N) {
    char *newarray = new char [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
        newarray[i] = array2[i] + 1;
    return newarray;
}
```

Both the functions allocates a new space, stores the incremented value of the given character array and returns the pointer to the allocated space. Call both the functions as,

```cpp
int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    char *oldArray = "abcd";
    char *newArray = Function2(Function1(oldArray, N), N);
}
```

There is nothing wrong in the function call `Function1` as it returns the pointer to the newly allocated space and passed it to `Function2` as `array2`. But at the end of `Function2`, the pointer `array2` will be deleted leaving the memory it holds as it is.  This results in a **memory leak**.

To avoid this leak, delete the memory the `array2` holds before the end of `Function2`.

```cpp
char* Function2(char *array2, int N) {
    ...
    delete[] array2;
    return newarray;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: as I see, you only use `delete[]` for `array2` in `Function2`, which is `Function1(oldArray, N)`, I understood this, but do I need `delete[] oldArrray` and `delete[] newArray` in `main()`? `oldArrray` is allocated by `new`.

Comment: Yes, you need to deallocate the memory allocated for `oldArray` and `newArray`.

Answer (score 0):

A *" pointer function"* isn't really a thing. I think you mean *function pointer*.

Yes, passing a *function pointer* as a parameter to a function is perfectly ok but you are not passing a *function pointer* as parameter here. You pass the value returned by a function that returns a pointer - and that's ok too.

It doesn't matter that it's returning a pointer. Compare with this pointer-free example:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int x) {
    return x + x;
}

int bar(int x) {
    return x * x;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << bar(foo(2)); // prints 16
}
```

You are not actually passing `foo(2)` as an argument to `bar()`. You pass what's returned from `foo(2)` (which is `4`) to `bar()`.

Comment: No, OP doesn't mean _function pointer_, they mean _function that returns a pointer_. Or perhaps just _pointer function_, in the same way that _function that returns an integer_ is sometimes called an _integer function_.

Comment: @TonyK Oh, I have never heard that before. Ok, the second part of the answer covers OP:s case I think?

Answer (score 0):

While your code, from the little you've shown, is perfectly valid it is also not what is recommended in modern C++.

Here are some problems with this kind of code:

1. Will the function free the pointer you have passed to it? In that case you must not free it again.
2. Will the function store the pointer somewhere where it will be accessible at a later time? In that case you can't free the pointer after the function call.
3. Is the function expecting a pointer to a single char, a C string or maybe even a pointer to an array of chars of some size specified in the documentation?
4. Is the function returning a pointer to a static buffer? In that case you must not free it.
5. Is the function returning a pointer to a single char? Then you have to `delete` it. Or is it returning a pointer to a char array? Then you have to `delete[]` it. Or maybe it returns a pointer that was created by `malloc()`. Then you must `free()` it.

What is `int N`? It looks suspiciously like that could be the size of the array the pointer points to. But sizes must be `size_t` because `int` isn't big enough to hold the size of larger arrays.

You should invest some time and read up on `std::array`, `std::vector`, `std::span`, `std::unique_ptr>` and `std::shared_ptr` and related classes. The https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines are also a good read. It's best to forget about raw pointers and C style arrays until you really need them.